# Improve the detection OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, threshold

I'm currently trying to detect eggs in a nest. For that, I'm using OpenCV.

Firstly, I took an image with 2 eggs. Then I converted it in HSV. And defined a range for the threshold.

But as you can see, when I trying to show the threshold window, everything isn't removed. So here is my question, how can I only detect eggs.

<------------Original--------------------|--------------- HSV--------------------|----------------- Threshold---------->
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: The color of the box (and floor) is very similar to the color of the eggs, that's probably why you are not getting a clean segmentation. There's a couple of things you can try. If the position of the eggs is reasonably constant, you could try to _crop_ the box out of the image. Another solution involves filtering your blobs based on *circularity*, with the idea that eggs have a very specific (and expected) circularity value. You could also try to perform *Hough Circle Transform*, but it might be a little overkill for this application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue from that point, you can simply apply to your threshold output [minAreaRect()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect) function which will help you draw a fitted rectangles for each contour. After that you can compare the lengths of those rectangles or you can also check the color density of those rectangles to reach the results.

As an alternative I tried [HoughCircle()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles), and its also able to find the eggs with appropriate parameters.

Here is result and code with houghcircle:

**Input Image:**

[image]

**Output Image:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // Loads an image
    Mat src_hough_circle = imread("/ur/image/directory/eggs.png", IMREAD_COLOR );

    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(src_hough_circle, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Mat gray_segmentation = gray.clone();

    //medianBlur(gray, gray, 5);
    GaussianBlur(gray,gray,Size(5,5),0);
    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(gray, circles, HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,
                 gray.rows/8,  // change this value to detect circles with different distances to each other
                 100, 30, 80, 170 // change the last two parameters
            // (min_radius & max_radius) to detect larger circles
    );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
    {
        Vec3i c = circles[i];
        Point center = Point(c[0], c[1]);
        // circle center
        circle( src_hough_circle, center, 1, Scalar(0,100,100), 3, LINE_AA);
        // circle outline
        int radius = c[2];
        circle( src_hough_circle, center, radius, Scalar(255,0,255), 3, LINE_AA);
    }

    imshow("detected circles", src_hough_circle);
    waitKey(0);



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yunus, for you're method, here is what I did, I don't know if it's better than you're method. (Sorry I didn't comment :( )

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA6P6.png)

**Code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int Compteur;
int Area;
int Contours;
Mat ImageSource;
Mat HSV;
Mat Image_Blur;
Mat Seuil;


int main() {

string FichierSource = "C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/TBT/cas.png";
ImageSource = imread(FichierSource);

cvtColor(ImageSource, HSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

inRange(HSV, Scalar(0, 39 , 149), Scalar(179, 255, 255), Seuil);

erode(Seuil, Seuil, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
dilate(Seuil, Seuil, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));

dilate(Seuil, Seuil, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
erode(Seuil, Seuil, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));

blur(Seuil, Image_Blur, Size(5, 5));

imshow("Image original", ImageSource);

imshow("Image convertie en HSV", HSV);

imshow("Image seuillé", Seuil);


Mat Threshold_Output;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

threshold(Image_Blur, Threshold_Output, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
findContours(Threshold_Output, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

vector<RotatedRect> minRect(contours.size());
vector<RotatedRect> minEllipse(contours.size());

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{

    Area = contourArea(contours[i]);
    Contours = contours[i].size();

    // -------------------------- DEBUG ZONE ---------------------------- 
    cout << "Contours de la zone : " << contourArea(contours[i]) << endl;
    cout << "Nombre de contours : " << contours[i].size() << endl;
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------ 

    if (Contours >= 90 && Contours <= 100) {
        if (Area >= 2000 && Area <= 3200) {
                minRect[i] = minAreaRect(Mat(contours[i]));
                minEllipse[i] = fitEllipse(Mat(contours[i]));
        }
            Compteur++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    Area = contourArea(contours[i]);
    Contours = contours[i].size();

    if (Contours >= 90 && Contours <= 100) {
        if (Area >= 2000 && Area <= 3200) {
            drawContours(ImageSource, contours, i, Scalar(0, 165, 255), 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point());

            ellipse(ImageSource, minEllipse[i], Scalar(0, 165, 255), 2);

            Point2f rect_points[4]; minRect[i].points(rect_points);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                line(ImageSource, rect_points[j], rect_points[(j + 1) % 4], Scalar(0, 165, 255));
        }
    }
}

imshow("Image Analysée", ImageSource);

cout << "Nombre d'oeufs : " << Compteur;

waitKey(0);

}
```